# Using spread operator in Styled-Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, styled-components

I'm new to *React* and *React-Spring* and practicing how to use it. 
There's really basic code from React-Spring document, and I want to convert it using *styled-components*. 
I converted code to *styled-components* but don't know how to change `...springs` in *styled-components*. 
Can I know how to apply it with using *styled-components*??

**document code:** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rw0hwy?file=/App.js&utm_medium=sandpack)

```
import '/index.css'
import { useSpring, animated } from '@react-spring/web'

export default function MyComponent() {
  const springs = useSpring({
    from: { x: 0 },
    to: { x: 100 },
  })

  return (
    <animated.div
      style={{
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        background: '#ff6d6d',
        borderRadius: 8,
        // don't know how to conver this part
        ...springs,
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

**my code:** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sound-hc9oqy?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useSpring, animated } from "@react-spring/web";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const springs = useSpring({
    from: { x: 0 },
    to: { x: 100 }
  });

  return (
    <Spring>
      <animated.div className="box">hi</animated.div>
    </Spring>
  );
}

const Spring = styled.div`
  border: 3px solid black;

  .box {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ff6d6d;
    border-radius: 8px;
    //this part doesn't work
    ...springs;
  }
`;
```

Comment: I just want to leave a comment and say that this is very well formatted question, complete with links to a functioning demo and also code in the question itself :) great job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having styled components or not doesn't affect your code: you should still spread the `springs` object directly into `<animated.div>`.

```
return (
  <Spring>
    <animated.div className="box" style={{ ...springs }} />
  </Spring>
);
```

If you truly want to offload all the styling to styled-components, you can create a new styled component that uses `animated.div` internally, i.e.:

```
const SpringBox = styled(animated.div)`
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ff6d6d;
  border-radius: 8px;
`;
```

Then you can update your template as such: but note that you are still spreading the `springs` in the JSX template and not passing it via styled components:

```
return (
  <Spring>
    <SpringBox style={{ ...springs }} />
  </Spring>
);
```

[image: Edit spring-forest-l5opvz]